# How to properly add rate if client IP does not exist from 'votes' table

Tags: php, sql

Hello Stack Overflow Community.

I've made two topics so far about rating system and happily with your help I've managed to achieve it. It works properly, just everyone can vote so I made it to add client's IP in database table 'votes' after each voting. I'd like to help me to make a check like: 1) If client has already voted to does not store its rating in database.

Also how can I avoid inserting postid and ip is they already exist in 'votes'?
For example, I vote once for post with id 2 and it creates:
 - id: 1
 - postid: 2
 - ip: client's IP

When vote once again for the same post it creates same info so this is useless and should be blocked..

Votes table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `votes` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `postid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `ip` varchar(15) DEFAULT NULL,
  `time` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

***Updated: /Full Rate.php/***

```
    <?php 

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "oregon";
$dbname = "project";

    try {   
        $connection = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
        $connection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);  

        $postid = $_POST['post_id'];
        $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
        $sql = $connection->prepare("SELECT postid, ip FROM votes WHERE ip = :ip");
        $sql->bindParam(':ip', $ip, PDO::PARAM_STR); 
        $sql->execute();
        if($sql->rowCount() > 0){
        die("You already voted");
        }   

        $postid = $_POST['post_id'];
        $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
        $sql = $connection->prepare("INSERT INTO votes (postid, ip) VALUES (:postid, :ip)");
        $sql->bindParam(':postid', $postid);
        $sql->bindParam(':ip', $ip);    
        $sql->execute();    

        if (isset( $_POST['slct']) && $_POST['slct'] === "1") {
            $rate = "1";
        } else if (isset( $_POST['slct']) && $_POST['slct'] === "2") {
            $rate = "2";
        } else if (isset( $_POST['slct']) && $_POST['slct'] === "3") {
            $rate = "3";
        } else if(isset( $_POST['slct']) && $_POST['slct'] === "4") {
            $rate = "4";
        } else if(isset( $_POST['slct']) && $_POST['slct'] === "5") {
            $rate = "5";
        } else {
            $rate = "0";
        }
        $id = $_POST['post_id'];
        $rating = $_POST['rate'];
        $clicks = $_POST['clicks'];
        $total_clicks = $clicks + '1';
        $max_rate = $rating + $rate;
        if($_POST['slct'] == "0") {
            $clicks = $_POST['clicks'];
            $total_clicks = $clicks + '0';
        }   

        $sql = $connection->prepare("UPDATE posts SET rate = :max_rate, clicks = :total_clicks WHERE id = :id");
        $sql->bindParam(':id', $id, PDO::PARAM_INT); 
        $sql->bindParam(':max_rate', $max_rate, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $sql->bindParam(':total_clicks', $total_clicks, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        if ($sql->execute()) {
            header('Location: ../index.php');
        } else { 
            echo "Error updating record: " . $e->getMessage();
        }
    }
    catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
    }
$connection = null;
?>
```

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

You can check using a `SELECT` query if the ip address is already in the database.

```
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$sql = $connection->prepare("SELECT postid, ip FROM votes WHERE ip = :ip");
$sql->bindParam(':ip', $id, PDO::PARAM_INT); 
$sql->execute();
if($sql->rowCount() > 0){
  // I prefer to use the rowCount() but also a fetch will be ok for your task
    echo 'You already voted.';
} else { // do your saving tasks here }
```

Comment: Well, maybe I do something wrong...it doesn't work, maybe I've integrated it wrongly. I'll upload the whole rate.php

Comment: @Stephan882 What problem do you encountered?

Comment: Well, I've tried to implement it and with your code, without your code, it acts in the same way...probably I've done something wrong, but it's understandable since I'm beginner with php ^^ The updated code above is clear without your select query, but I can add it once again so you guys can check if I do something wrong or the problem comes from somewhere else.

Comment: I can suggest you to use only the `INSERT` query, so with only one operation you can insert the ip, the postid and the rating inside the database. Another suggestion (but maybe I'm wrong) is to separate the update and the insert operations so you can debug more efficently your code.

Answer (score 0):

Before I post the whole code I want you to try this. If it works then I'll post second part with the `UPDATE` query

```
<?php
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "oregon";
    $dbname = "project";

    try {   
        $connection = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
        $connection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);  

        $sql = $connection->prepare("SELECT * FROM votes");
        if ($sql->execute()) {
            $row_votes = $sql->fetch();
            if ($row_votes['postid'] == $_POST['post_id'] && $row_votes['ip'] == $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']) {
                echo "You've already voted for this post. You cannot vote again.";
            } else {
                $sql = $connection->prepare("INSERT INTO votes (postid, ip) VALUES (:postid, :ip)");
                $sql->bindParam(':postid', $postid);
                $sql->bindParam(':ip', $ip);    
                $postid = $_POST['post_id'];
                $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
                if ($sql->execute()) {
                    echo "INSERT was successeful";
                } else {
                    echo "INSERT was unseccessful";
                }
            }
        } else {
            echo "Could not execute query";
        }
    }
    catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
    }

    $connection = null;
?>
```

Comment: Well yeah it works, but it still adds new rows (same) in DB even if it says "Unsuccessful" ^^

Comment: I've managed to fix, but the way I did a bit sucks. However it's really appreciated that you help me for everything :P